# Mocking ToListAsync on a Mock<DbSet<T>> using Moq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mocking, moq

I've got a method that converts a List to a DbSet which I use when mocking the data my database context should return. For example:

```
MockedDatabaseContext.Setup(u => u.SomeTable).Returns(GetDbSet(ListOfItems));
```

However the method I'm trying to write a unit test for uses the ToListAsync method at one point to convert from IQueryable to a List.

**Is there a way using the Moq framework to make a setup on the ToListAsync method call?**

I've tried this:

```
dbSet.Setup(d => d.ToListAsync(CancellationToken.None)).Returns((Task<List<T>>) Task.CompletedTask);
```

But this throws a 'ThrowIfSetupExpressionInvolvesUnsupportedMember' exception on the line above.

Comment: Not a real answer to your question, but, [the EF team](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/6631) agrees that you should not attempt to mock EF. I'd suggest you to look at using the InMemory database package for testing. If you want to go down your route, note that you will have to implement most stuff manually

Comment: `ToListAsync` is an extension method, which wont work as Moq cannot setup/mock extension methods.

Comment: May be it is better for you to mock `DbSet` [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47775814/can-i-make-my-entity-framework-dbset-call-my-table-valued-function-when-selectin/47787125#47787125)

Comment: This question has been answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41324783/unit-testing-tolistasync-using-an-in-memory/41327224

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unit-testing .ToListAsync() using an in-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41324783/unit-testing-tolistasync-using-an-in-memory)